# stability of two moons

Tags: science-based, physics, moons, orbital-mechanics

**Is there a good way to measure the orbital stability of two moons around a planet?**

Here I mean something like a mathematical constant or an equation that can approximate the stability of the orbits of the two moons since the two moons are relatively close to each other and I need to calculate how stable their orbits are.

My question does not involve a specific planetary system, It is a general scientific question.

Comment: What sort of stability are you looking for.  That's a three body problem, so they are by definition unstable by astronomy's definitions.  But they may be "stable enough" by your terms

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "the two moons are relatively close to each other."  Moons that orbit at the same distance from the planet will also have the same orbital period. See Kepler's 3rd Law. The moment your two moons have a different distance from the planet, they will have different orbital periods. That means they'll spend some of the time on the 'same side' of the planet, and other times across from each other on opposite sides for planet.

Comment: You need to give masses and distances for the three bodies involved if there's any chance to answer this.  Note that the three body problem in physics has *no* analytical solution (no nice formula - no formula at all in fact) and even numerical solutions are not necessarily useful for what you want to know.

Comment: This probably belongs on Astronomy SE. Please close this question and move it to the Astronomy site.

Comment: @fasterthanlight Questions that can be asked on another stack are not automatically off-topic on the WB.SE. Please see [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate) for more details.

Comment: @fasterthanlight I'm quite certain we've a lot of quite technical answers about astronomy and astrophysics right here on WB SE, including those using the hard-science tag.

Comment: FYI: [Orbital resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_resonance)

Comment: @Otkin In this case I agree, it's the sort of thing we deal with here all the time - usually given "Worldbuilding context" that is. Where this question falls down is lack of such context and lack of prior research. (Which doesn't merit closure here, just a [downvote](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/445/55743)).

Comment: Technically, the only way to simulate this is via an nbody simulation.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I agree with most of what you said. However, I object to your 'lack of prior research'. Indeed, the post does not say anything about prior research. Nonetheless, it is not correct (and not very kind) to assume that no research has been done. Please consider asking the OP directly whether they have done any research or not. The overall atmosphere of this community would greatly benefit from people asking more clarification questions. I hope we can agree on that.

Comment: While closing it in WB is not warranted, I can't stop noting that Astronomy (or even Maths) offers much better chances for a pertinent answer. That is to say: if s/he really needs a "professional" answer, I strongly encourage @Bowman to post the question there.

Comment: @Otkin At this point it's been 19 hours since posting and there are many requests for clarification which have to this point not resulted in the question being updated. Maybe the world has lots of context, lots of worldbuilding has gone-on behind the scenes to prompt the question - along with a great-deal of research - but the question lacks it - in the sense that none is shown (I don't profess mindreading to be one of my skills). I guess it's important that I explicitly state "show your worldbuilding-context" and "show your research".

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Please direct your requests for more worldbuilding context to the OP. No matter how much I would like to help you I am not the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Numerical Modelling Is The Way

As stated in comments, the three body problem is an unsolved problem in physics, which includes all two-moons-and-planet system. No "nice" equation exists, although the numerical model method give you an answer with some "nice" concepts and a thing to measure.

The basic approach is to figure out the six gravitational forces in the system, apply those forces to each body (moon/planet) over a small time step to get new positions, and repeat.

And repeat.

And repeat.

And repeat.

...

And repeat.

Until the heat death of the universe, the power goes out, the computer breaks, things crash into each other (in your model or otherwise), or you get tired of it.

Where is the payoff? Well, you count how many steps until one of those above conditions happen in/to your model, and that is how you measure stability.

There are a lot of little questions when doing this that get the pendants really going. Like... is your time step short enough? Did you check for collisions? Did you check for bodies passing through each other? Did you go long enough? Did you account for any liquid rock which may be going on? Did you model them anywhere along the sliding scale from three solid bodies to every atom in each body? (They will make uncomfortable noises no matter what you say: either uncomfortable for you or uncomfortable for them.) What if each body has a magnetic field? And it goes on...